# Nodejs ,mysql as backend

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am working in nodejs and my sql  as backend I want to update paticular column in mysql  as per client wish how can i do? please Help

```
//update student record
       app.put('/students/:id',(req, res) => {
      let sql = "UPDATE students SET 
 
    firstName='"+req.body.firstName+"',lastName='"+req.body.lastName+"',email='"+req.body.email+"',address='"+req.body.address+"',phoneNumber='"+req.body.phoneNumber+"',feesPaid='"+req.body.feesPaid+"'  WHERE Id="+req.params.id;
  let query = conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
   if(err) throw err;
  res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
  });
  });
```

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

This is the example code for your update

```
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var sql = "UPDATE students SET firstName = 'Deep' WHERE Id =" + req.params.id;
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result.affectedRows + " record(s) updated");
  });
});
```

As per yours here below:

```
app.put('/students/:id',(req, res) => {
      let sql = "UPDATE students SET firstName='"+req.body.firstName+"'  WHERE Id="+req.params.id;
      let query = conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
      });
});
```

Comment: I want a to use particular column in Thunder Client not in Node js

Comment: I will write all columns in Node Js code. I want to use a particular column in the Thunder client. what shall I do?